# Include an unofficial Julia package in a REQUIRE file?

Tags: julia

I'd like to list an "unofficial" Julia package in my package's REQUIRE file. (That is, the package I'd like to list can only be installed with Pkg.clone, not Pkg.add.) How can I configure my package so that this unofficial package gets installed automatically, when someone clones my package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this at this time, but it is a requested feature. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7737) and this [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/julia-users/eHINShc-1XM/F-jJ7UxKQDsJ) thread.